# eBay Finding API - findItemByKeyword search result returning attribute field as null

Tags: attributes, ebay-api

I am using eBay's Finding API (c#) to find items by keyword. I need to be able to see if the model number matches the item I am looking for.

I was under the impression that the MPN of a item is included in the `Attributes` of the `searchItems` that eBay returns, however every single one of the 100 search items returned for the keyword have their attributes set to `null`. When I click on the link in the object that is the Listing URL I see the MPN clearly defined on the page.

Am I looking under the wrong rock?
Here is the link to the eBay page of a item being returned with `Atrribute[] field = null`

http://www.ebay.com/itm/Western-Digital-Caviar-Green-3-TB-Internal-5400-RPM-WD30EZRX-Hard-Drive-/300856751436?pt=US_Internal_Hard_Disk_Drives

Thanks!

Comment: Could you take the image out and post the actual output that you wish to share? Images are hard to read.

Comment: Sorry really just showing that the attribute[] field is returning null

Comment: Alex, did you get answer from ebay on this ?
According to the following [doc](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/Concepts/map_FindItemsAdvanced_2_FindingService.html) directing to move from Shoping API to Trading API,
there is no field associated with the SearchResult.ItemArray.Item.ItemSpecifics in the Shoping API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommmend that you go through the [API docs reference](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/CallRef/index.html).

I wouldn't be fooled by whats happening on Ebay site v/s what you are seeing. Your app and ebay.com may not be using the same services behind the scenes

Check out the raw response of the service. I believe this is the service URI that you would be interested in -

http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=YourAppID&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&REST-PAYLOAD&keywords=harry%20potter%20phoenix

Check if the response contains `<MPN>` tags. I am unable to do so, because I dont have an app id with ebay.

I don't think this will have `<MPN>` tag - the [API reference for findItemsByKeywords](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/callref/finditemsbykeywords.html) does not list the `<MPN>` as part of its output.

However, if you need `<MPN>` it is available as per `GetItem` call. Here is the [reference.](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GetItem.html)

The

Comment: Thanks for the URL idea though it only seem to prove my point further. No matter what search I place eBay does not return any attributes. It would seem to me that they haven't really developed this part of the api. I would rather not have to make ID specific calls as I don't want to have to make a new call for every item that I get back since that can be up to 100 additional calls for each keyword query.

Comment: True - all i am saying is that if the API does not have the support, you could be certain that you are not missing anything. Might be worth checking with Ebay on this.

Answer (score 0):

[GetMultipleItems](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetMultipleItems.html#Samples) in Shopping API returns "attributes" for 20 items. You need to add "IncludeSelector=ItemSpecifics" and the list of item ids in the request.